# how can i join the two different query statement,which contain different table ,column name

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, navicat

```
SELECT
bookingReference,
SUM(amount)
FROM
rates_Booking
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-30'
GROUP BY bookingReference;

SELECT booking_type.`name` as booking_type 
FROM booking_type
LEFT JOIN booking ON booking_type.`name`=booking.booking_type;
```

i want to join both table. i want result like this:

```
column1            column2   column3
----------
bookingReference    sum(amount)   booking_type
----------
0993979-00          £500     booking
----------
```

Comment: there are relation between the 3 tables? if yes on which column .. if not how the value from the two query are related ?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer the question. Given only the columns shown, there doesn't appear to be any common columns that form a relationship between `rates_Booking` and `booking_type`.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @scaisEdge- only rate_bookings and booking table has common column name "amount".

Comment: @spencer7593- no common column between rates_booking and booking_type.

Comment: Thank you to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there is some joining column between the first and second dataset.  All I did in this case was join the both on a booking reference column (assuming this column is in both datasets).
Really hard to determine with the amount of information given.  But if there is a reference column then it would be a simple inner join

```
SELECT
A.bookingReference,SUM(A.amount), booking_type.`name` as booking_type 
FROM
rates_Booking A
inner join booking_type B ON A.bookingReference = B.bookingReference
left join booking  ON booking_type.`name`=booking.booking_type
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-30'
GROUP BY A.bookingReference,booking_type.`name`;
```

Comment: This same query give me the error -                                                        [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'booking_type.name' in 'field list'

Comment: sub query is  possible with left join and 2 different select queries.

Comment: I was just guessing column names because there is not enough information within your question to give a correct answer